# PolylineOptions not drawing in mass, Android GoogleMap

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

So I have my GoogleMap drawing one line, but no matter how I put it the following code just doesn't work at all. I feel like there is something I'm missing in the documentation or something, because this has been driving me crazy. Here is the code in question.

```
store = new LocationStore();
store.readFromFile(getResources());
Iterator<Path> it = store.getPaths().iterator();
Map<Long, LatLng> points = store.getPositions();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    PolylineOptions line = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.RED).visible(true);
    List<Long> pointIds = it.next().getPoints();
    for (Long id : pointIds) {
        line.add(points.get(id));
    }
    map.addPolyline(line);
}
PolylineOptions line = new PolylineOptions();
line.add(new LatLng(33.3406000, -84.6105000));
line.add(new LatLng(33.4469000, -84.5103000));
map.addPolyline(line);
```

From this I get only one line, the one at the bottom where I specifically define the `LatLng`. What am I missing?

Path is just a holder for the id's for that path, as well as an id for the path. The following are the only things in it, along with some getters and setters:

```
Long id;
ArrayList<Long> points;
```

Comment: you should set breakpoints or log out each iteration to see if the values are what you expect

Comment: I've done that and everything looks right, I'm just baffled as to why the map won't show it

Comment: Are you sure the ids of the Path are matching the ids of the Map ? I don't think this is a GoogleMap problem. Adding multiple Polylines works fine. I am not sure, whether line.add() silently accepts null. In this case, you would not get aware of a mismatch of your ids at all. Assign the result of points.get(id) to an intermediate variable and check (by logging or debugging), whether it really returns a LatLng.

Comment: @user2808624 Just checked that, the `LatLng`'s are all returning correctly

Comment: @user2808624 Ah figured it out, all of the points, no matter the index, are all the same `LatLng`. That'll do it!